# NodeJS: Trying to upload a file to a user's Firebase storage bucket once it has been processed by an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to a user's Firebase storage bucket once it has been processed by an API i'm working with. I'm doing this from the server side.

The issue here is that I need to reference the UID from the backend in order to send it across to firebase.

I've got everything working with the API but when I try to initiate Firebase it throws-back an error about it not being initialised. I have already initialised Firebase in my start.js and referenced Firebase in the file that I'm writing the code in. I guess I could call it via 'admin.firebase' but not sure if that makes sense as I want the users to upload via their uid. Any help would be awesome

Here is the post request initialising the API from the backend. The point i'm trying to initialise the firebase upload is where i call 'console.log(JOB COMPLETE)':

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const axios = require('axios');
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const storage = require("firebase/storage");
const auth = require("firebase/auth");


const
{
  BucketsApi,
  ObjectsApi,
  PostBucketsPayload,
  DerivativesApi,
  JobPayload,
  JobPayloadInput,
  JobPayloadOutput,
  JobSvfOutputPayload
} = require('forge-apis');

const
{
  getClient,
  getInternalToken
} = require('./common/oauth');
const config = require('../config');

let router = express.Router();

// Middleware for obtaining a token for each request.
router.use(async (req, res, next) =>
{
  const token = await getInternalToken();
  req.oauth_token = token;
  req.oauth_client = getClient();
  next();
});
   

 router.post('/objects', multer(
{
  dest: 'uploads/'
}).single('fileToUpload'), async (req, res, next) =>
{

  fs.readFile(req.file.path, async (err, data) =>
  {
    if (err)
    {
      next(err);
    }
    try
    {
      // Upload an object to bucket using [ObjectsApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject).
      const response = await new ObjectsApi().uploadObject(req.body.bucketKey, req.file.originalname, data.length, data,
      {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
      if (response.statusCode === 200)
      {
        let buff = Buffer(response.body.objectId)
        let job = new JobPayload();
        job.input = new JobPayloadInput();
        job.input.urn = buff.toString('base64');
        job.output = new JobPayloadOutput([
          new JobSvfOutputPayload()
        ]);
        job.output.formats[0].type = 'svf';
        job.output.formats[0].views = ['2d', '3d'];
        try
        {
          console.log('translating');
          const token = req.oauth_token.access_token;

          // Submit a translation job using [DerivativesApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate).
          await new DerivativesApi().translate(job,
          {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
          setInterval(function()
          {
            console.log('polling');
            var config = {
              method: 'get',
              url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + buff.toString('base64') + '/manifest',
              headers:
              {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Referer': 'http://localhost:3000/view',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
              }
            };

            axios(config)
              .then(function(response)
              {
                response = response.data;
                console.log(response.progress, response.status);
                if (response.progress === "complete")
                {
                  if (response.status === "success")
                  {
                    console.log("JOB COMPLETE");
                  }

                }

              })
              .catch(function(error)
              {
                console.log(error);
                return;
              });
          }, 2000);
          res.status(200).end();
        }
        catch (err)
        {
          next(err);
          return;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('bad')
        res.status(response.statusCode).end(response);
      }
    }
    catch (err)
    {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There isnt enough information here for us to help you.  Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Ok no problem, I will add more information

Comment: I've updated the question. let me know if this is enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to call firebase from the backend using the following code:

```
// POST /api/forge/oss/objects - uploads new object to given bucket.
// Request body must be structured as 'form-data' dictionary
// with the uploaded file under "fileToUpload" key, and the bucket name under "bucketKey".
router.post('/objects', multer(
{
  dest: 'uploads/'
}).single('fileToUpload'), async (req, res, next) =>
{

  fs.readFile(req.file.path, async (err, data) =>
  {
    if (err)
    {
      next(err);
    }
    try
    {
      // Upload an object to bucket using [ObjectsApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadObject).
      const response = await new ObjectsApi().uploadObject(req.body.bucketKey, req.file.originalname, data.length, data,
      {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
      if (response.statusCode === 200)
      {
        let buff = Buffer(response.body.objectId)
        let job = new JobPayload();
        job.input = new JobPayloadInput();
        job.input.urn = buff.toString('base64');
        job.output = new JobPayloadOutput([
          new JobSvfOutputPayload()
        ]);
        job.output.formats[0].type = 'svf';
        job.output.formats[0].views = ['2d', '3d'];
        try
        {
          console.log('translating');
          const token = req.oauth_token.access_token;

          // Submit a translation job using [DerivativesApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate).
          await new DerivativesApi().translate(job,
          {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
          setInterval(function()
          {
            console.log('polling');
            var config = {
              method: 'get',
              url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + buff.toString('base64') + '/manifest',
              headers:
              {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Referer': 'http://localhost:3000/view',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
              }
            };

            axios(config)
              .then(function(response)
              {
                response = response.data;
                console.log(response.progress, response.status);
                if (response.progress === "complete")
                {
                  if (response.status === "success")
                  {
                    console.log("JOB COMPLETE");
                    // upload to firebase here

                    const idToken = req.body.idToken;

                    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                    if (user)
                    {
                      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
                        .then(function(decodedToken)
                        {
                          if (decodedToken.uid === user.uid)
                          {
                            req.user = user.uid;
                            console.log(user);
                            return next();

                          }
                        }).catch(function(error)
                        {
                          //Handle error
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      console.log("There is no current user.");
                    }

                  }

                }

              })
              .catch(function(error)
              {
                console.log(error);
                return;
              });
          }, 2000);
          res.status(200).end();
        }
        catch (err)
        {
          next(err);
          return;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('bad')
        res.status(response.statusCode).end(response);
      }
    }
    catch (err)
    {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
  });
});
```